# Can P&T assets be integrated with drive and push uploads to youtube?

Tags: expressionengine

I'm currently working on a project that requires a simple yet complete workflow for media management from within the EE (2.5+) control panel... specifically youtube videos.

I know that [P&T Assets](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/assets) (2.1+) supports google cloud storage and in light of that, we would like to use it to upload videos to it and what would be ideal then is if there was a way for Assets or Google to post to youtube on upload complete.

Is this at all possible?

I know we can use wygwam to embed videos within an entry and can even use an addon such as [Antena](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/antenna) to embed youtube videos but we would like to manage it from within the CP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible without extending assets significantly, you could do something with the youtube API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) and trigger a a youtube upload once assets has finished a upload.